# I want to fail docker compose if my first task fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose, task

I want to fail docker compose if my first task fail and it should not move to other tasks mentioned in the compose file.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Docker-compose is not a script; it's the definition of an environment. The environment is described in the docker-compose file by defining each service that make up the environment.

Of course, it is sometimes necessary to have a service fail during initialization.

This can be done by, for example:

- defining a Dockerfile for the service, which performs initialization during image creation, or
- defining an `entrypoint` script, which does initialization when starting a container based on the image.

The point is, docker-compose shouldn't fail. The services should fail.

---

If you absolutely need to fail on startup, you can define a dependency between services by using [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends-on) to define the order that containers are started; like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Please note, the dependent services will start as soon as the parent services are `started`... It will not wait for them to be in a `ready` state.

Comment: Thanks Eric, i'll try your mentioned method :)